# Writing notes on printed Qur'an

Tags: quran, tafseer

As Salam Walaikum brothers and sisters. I am currently investing more time in studying the Qur'an. I thought that the best way to do this is by writing things down in pencil on the pages of the Surah that I'm learning.

I realize that making those notes in a valuable Qur'an is both haram and disrespectful. That's why I printed the English translation of the Surah on paper. Is it okay to make notes on that version?

May Allah (swt) reward you all!

Comment: What is your evidence for saying it is not appropriate to write notes on a printed moshaf? You should know that you can't make notes on the Qur'an as the Qur'an refers to the recited and orally transmitted content of the moshaf!

Comment: That is my question, I don't know if it's appropriate or not since it's haram to write them in a Qur'an. I am new to Islam so I don't know if it's allowed or not. However, I know the importance of an authentic Qur'an

Comment: Note that we worship Allah not a book.

Comment: Yes indeed, but it's for example haram to burn a Qur'an or to write in one. So I thought that maybe that would be the same for a printed translation since it is the word of Allah (swt)

Comment: @DeveloperOfDreams You don't seem to understand. Qur'an = The Revelation itself. Printed Qur'an = Mushaf (in Arabic). Any rule regarding the Mushaf is a result of Ijtima' of scholars because printed copies of Qur'an didn't exist during the time of Prophet Muhammad (SAW) so that there can be any rules governing it. Writing notes is not changing the Qur'an. It is just akin to any other form of highlighting of Mushaf and symbols of harakat that came later to help in it's proper recitation.